# NSURLConnection Saving Variable Does not work

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am making an (asynchronous) url request.

In the delegate function *connectionDidFinishLoading* I assign the response of the server to an instance variable.

I wait a few seconds after I make the request and I am SURE that I have received the response.

I have a button linked to an IBAction which prints out this variable to NSLog, but it is ALWAYS null.

I have no idea what's going on. Does the url request start a new thread and any of the variables saved, aren't accessible in the main thread... or why on earth can I not ever see any of my saved variables.

I can properly use the received data inside the *connectionDidFinishLoading*, but when I assign this data to instance variables and try to access them outside the function they are always null.

TL;DR
How on earth do I save the responses or a url request for later use!?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...why don't you put the NSLog() into your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method? Because it sounds like all you're doing is assigning the response into a variable in your delegate method, and not logging anything. Obviously seeing some code helps a bit here - but being 'sure' isn't the same as being without doubt.

Comment: thanks for the response. The code is spread across multiple classes and I think would be very unclear. I will do my best to explain: right now I am logging it in the delegate, that is how I know I am receiving the correct data. The problem occurs when I save that data to a instance variable and try to access it at another later time...its always null. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are not retaining the memory so it is being automatically freed.  The instance variable you are assigning, is it a property with "retain" or "copy" specified?  You can also manually call retain on the object itself after you set it:

```
[myString retain];
```

Using a property is a better way to manage, example .H:

```
@interface MyClass: Object    {
    NSString *myString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
```

elsewhere in .M:

```
@synthesize myString    
...
...
self.myString = ...
```

This ensures the string is not released on you until you want to:

```
[myString release];
self.myString = NULL;
```